# Different results using Node.js' module.exports in Yeoman

Tags: node.js, yeoman

I am receiving different results with `module.exports` and would appreciate someone helping me shore up the obvious hole in my knowledge.

From the following code, I receive the result listed below it.

```
var generators = require('yeoman-generator');

var MyBase = generators.Base.extend({
    helper: function() {
        console.log('this is a helper method');
    }
});

module.exports = MyBase.extend({
    method1: function() {
        console.log('method 1 just ran');
    }
});
```

Result:

```
method 1 just ran
```

But if I place `module.exports` on its own line, and assign `MyBase` to it, I get the following result. Here is the code:

```
var generators = require('yeoman-generator');

var MyBase = generators.Base.extend({
    helper: function() {
        console.log('this is a helper method');
    }
});

MyBase.extend({
    method1: function() {
        console.log('method 1 just ran');
    }
});

module.exports = MyBase
```

Result:

```
this is a helper method
```

What is causing the difference in outputs?

Comment: is it possible .extend returns a new object instead of modifying the old one in place?

Comment: @JonahWilliams It's possible. But I thought the whole point of `extend` was to **add** to the functionality of the object being extended, rather than overwrite it. No?

Comment: If that were the case, then extending the base would overwrite it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't been able to completely reproduce your issue, but the problem is almost certainly the fact that calling .extend on a generator returns a new generator with both the current and extended properties.

```
var generators = require('yeoman-generator');

var MyBase = generators.Base.extend({
  helper: function() {
    console.log('this is a helper method');
  }
});

// Capture the output of the .extend function
var MyBase2 = MyBase.extend({
  method1: function() {
    console.log('method 1 just ran');
  }
});

module.exports = MyBase2
```

Alternatively, you could just define multiple properties in one go

```
var MyBase = generators.Base.extend({
  helper: function() {
    console.log('this is a helper method');
  },
  method1: function() {
    console.log('method 1 just ran');
  }
});
```

Comment: Your solution works. But I'm trying to understand the hole in my knowledge about how `module.exports` works, as applies to the above scenario.

Comment: module.exports is just an object, and require just pulls in that object.  So in  case #1 above, you set it equal to the output of the MyBase.extend function.  therefore the extended object is imported.  http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-module-exports-exports-node-js/

Comment: Right, but why does `MyBase.extend()` not cause `method1` to run in the second code example in my question above? That's what I'm really trying to understand.

Comment: because it does not modify the object in place - it returns a new object.  you are exporting the old object